# My pygame slider moves back to the default position when mouse click is released rather than staying where it was left

Tags: python, pygame

When I click on my slider object, I can move the slider around in the given boundaries of the box as expected however when I let go of my mouse button, the blue slider teleports to the left side of the box.

How can I get it so the slider is left when I release the mouse button?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIDTH = 1820
HEIGHT = 960
res = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(res)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
GRAY = [125, 125, 125]
BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
BLUE = [0, 0, 155]

class ui(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, colour, name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.c = colour
        self.n = name
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",25)

    

class slider(ui):
    def __init__(self, x, y,width,height):
        super().__init__(x,y,width,height,GRAY,"null")
        
        
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)) #Bounding box of slider


    def click(self, event):
        bound = False
        button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if x >= self.x and x <= self.x + self.w:
            if y >= self.y and y <= self.y + self.h:
                bound = True
        else:
            bound = False

        if bound == True:
            if button[0] != 0:
                self.x = x
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.x = x
            
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (self.x, self.y, 10, self.h)) #actual clickable slider itself


def main():
    done = False
    while not done:
        event_list = pygame.event.get()
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        slider1 = slider(250,250,300,100)
        slider1.draw()
        slider1.click(event)


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
main()
```

I've tried writing some detection for when the user lets go of the mouse button.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
   self.x = x
```

That works once I let go of the mouse button but then teleports once I move my mouse off the slider or input any key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two mistakes in your code:

- The slider is deleted and created again each frame.
- You don't move the bar on the slider but instead the whole slider itself.

To fix this only create `slider1` once and have a variable that traces the position:

```
...

class slider(ui):
    def __init__(self, x, y,width,height):
        super().__init__(x,y,width,height,GRAY,"null")
        self.pos = x
        
        
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)) #Bounding box of slider


    def click(self, event):
        bound = False
        button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if x >= self.x and x <= self.x + self.w:
            if y >= self.y and y <= self.y + self.h:
                bound = True
        else:
            bound = False

        if bound == True:
            if button[0] != 0:
                self.pos = x # (changed to pos)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.pos = x
            
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (self.pos, self.y, 10, self.h)) #actual clickable slider itself


def main():
    done = False
    slider1 = slider(250,250,300,100) # add
    while not done:
        event_list = pygame.event.get()
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        #slider1 = slider(250,250,300,100) (remove)
        slider1.draw()
        slider1.click(event)


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
    pygame.quit()
main()
```

Now you have a slider. But to make the movement more intuitively you might only move the slider when the mouse button started to be pressed on the slider:

```
...
class slider(ui):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, GRAY, "null")
        self.pos = x
        self.pressed = False
        self.bound = False
        
        
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)) # Bounding box of slider


    def click(self):
        button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if x >= self.x and x <= self.x + self.w and y >= self.y and y <= self.y + self.h:
            if True in button and not self.pressed:
                self.bound = True

        if not True in button:
            self.bound = False

        if self.bound:
            self.pos = max(self.x, min(self.x + self.w, x))
            
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (self.pos, self.y, 10, self.h)) # actual clickable slider itself

        self.pressed = True in button


def main():
    done = False
    slider1 = slider(250, 250, 300, 100)
    
    while not done:
        event_list = pygame.event.get()
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        
        slider1.draw()
        slider1.click()

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        
    pygame.quit()

    
main()
```